# How to Send Verification Email Again

Tags: php, laravel

My website is already on production, some users signed up, but I realized that email smtp was not working, so the email never were sent.

In the table users, I have a list of user with the column email_verified_at empty.
How could I send the verification email again programmatically. I don't want to add this functionality, it's just for executing once.

Regards

Nelson

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use queues, which comes in Laravel by default.

So, in your case, if an email sending for an example fails, queue logic will continue trying until it get sent eventually.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues